ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : 404ing specifically when it is an application in a subdirectory
I apologize in advance for this question, because I know a million variations of this have been asked, but I am stumped after pouring through them all.
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project. I am using the publish folder approach to simply deploy it to my IIS server. The application itself runs perfectly locally and it runs perfectly fine as its own site with its own port binding.
However, when I:

deploy the folder as a subdirectory
convert it to an application
put it on its own pool with No Managed Code
enable anonymous authentication

it 404s, no matter how I define the routes in the code or tweak the application pools, recycle the pools, restart the sites, et cetera.
AspNetCoreV2 handler is all well and accounted for. Web.config is completely untouched from how the folder publish generates it.
https://gist.github.com/sombraguerrero/f200142810ec7e5b9d3941b290ba0252

Enable Failed Request Tracing and look at the generated log. Do you see anything obvious ni there?

"Web.config is completely untouched from how the folder publish generates it." - how does your web.config compare to the applicationHost.config? Is your Application-scope defined in applicationHost.config, the site-root web.config, or the subdirectory web.config? Do you have any locked config areas in parent configs?

@Dai  applicationHost.config seems fine. I just redid my folder and site structure fresh, along with the default app pool to try and match it a little more closely. Still no luck. Other than that, I only have a web.host file at the subdirectory level.

I have added a public gist containing relevant information. My controller name is datexreft1 and all I have under there is a Get() definition with only [controller] defined as the route.

I got it. I just needed to read more current posts about MapControllers to understand how to appropriately decorate my attributes. If there weren't so many blogs and posts about this, I would blame myself for being negligent, but I just don't see why Microsoft has had to change this space so much over the years and confuse everybody!
